# ansible-core copy working, ansbile copy failing

Tags: ansible

Till recently I was using an ansible-core version in a venv (2.15.3)

I now installed ansbile 2.10.8, note the first version is ansible-**core** the 2nd is ansbile.

In one playbook, I want to copy from a fileserver (frel), to my target server.

```
- name: Copy files from frel server
  synchronize:
    src: /exp/machine_conf.yml
    dest: /etc/opt/test/
  delegate_to: frs-01
  become: yes
```

When running the playbook from my ansible-core install it works fine, but when I use my ansible install I get :

```
"No such file or directory"
```

When running in verbose mode -vvv, I can see that the destination is changed from

```
user_target@10.0.0.1/etc/opt/test/
```

to

```
user_source@10.0.0.1/etc/opt/test/
```

Note the user that is used is different. (ip is the ip of the destination).

How should I use the copy module in ansible, that the correct user is used for the destination?

Comment: Please add the contents of the playbook and inventory, the exact command you use in both examples and verbose output

Comment: Are this different settings? Different inventories, maybe?

Comment: @MarcinSłowikowski I excluded the project in a playbook with only the above task, I use the same inventory file and playbook in both runs. I will paste the inventory soon ( currently no access).